# Formatting datetime in Python properly for Google Calendar API

Tags: python, datetime, google-calendar-api

Trying to format the datetime properly to call the Google Calendar API properly.  Below is a code excerpt of the relevant part of my code.

```
import datetime as DT
now = DT.datetime.today()
seven_days = DT.timedelta(days=7)
oneWeekAgo = now - seven_days

print('Getting the 7 events starting 1 week ago from today: ')
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=oneWeekAgo,
                                      maxResults=7, singleEvents=True).execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])
```

Basically I am trying to modify the sample code from here:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

The sample code works great for me, and I just want to modify it to change the date of calendar events to retrieve to one week ago.  I don't understand the format that service.events().list requires.

Thank you for your patience and advice.

Comment: ```2021-02-07T21:01:43``` this is the format that the calendar api from google is expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the same solution in the example from Google (https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python), I just had to figure out how to change the date to one week ago without changing the format.

I added in a maximum time as today as well.

```
  # Call the Calendar API for one week ago through today
now = datetime.today()

oneWeekAgo = now - (DT.timedelta(days=7))

# Let's get this dateTime into the proper format for Google Calendar API

oneWeekAgo = oneWeekAgo.isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time

now = now.isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time

print('Getting up to 20 events starting 1 week ago from today: ')
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=oneWeekAgo,
                                      timeMax=now, maxResults=20, singleEvents=True,
                                      orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])
```

Answer (score 1):

The client libraries make it easier to use the APIs, but they can only use the methods publicly available. That is to say that you should look for the information about the parameters `timeMax` and `timeMin` in the reference to the method `Events.list` in the official API docs here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#parameters

From the docs above linked you have:

> `timeMax` is of type datetime, and described as: Upper bound (exclusive) for an event's start time to filter by. Optional. The default is not to filter by start time. Must be an RFC3339 timestamp with mandatory time zone offset, for example, 2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00, 2011-06-03T10:00:00Z. Milliseconds may be provided but are ignored. If timeMin is set, timeMax must be greater than timeMin.